# Optimization problem with integral

Tags: optimization

I have here quite a easy optimization problem, however I can't figure out how to solve it. Given a definite integral from a to b. I need to find values a and b such that the value of the integral is largest.
How do I solve su

Comment: If $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx$ has a closed form on $a$ and $b$, you should solve: $min\hspace{2mm} F(a)-F(b)$, whose solution depends on $F$.

Comment: You need to give some more information.

Comment: It's a simple quadratic integral  x^2 + x - 6

Comment: In this case $$\int_{a}^{b}(x^2+x-6) dx = \left(\frac{1}{3}b^3 + \frac{1}{2}b^2 -6b \right) - \left(\frac{1}{3}a^3 + \frac{1}{2}a^2 -6a \right).$$ Thus, the integral is maximum if $a \rightarrow -\infty$ and $b \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Solve the integral with $a$ and $b$ as the limits, and then depending on the form of the answer there are different ways to maximise it with respect to $a$ and $b$. Either you can see the answer immediately, or you differentiate and find values of $a$ and $b$ for which the derivative is zero and find which of those is the maximum.